# Solution verification for finding flaw in proof

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation

> Let $a,b,c$ be real numbers, with $a\ne0$. Find the flaw in the proof that $-b/2a$ is a solution of $ax^2+bx+c=0$
>
> (Fake proof.) We have $x$ and $y$ as solutions. According to Viète, $x+y= -b/a$. Since $x$ and $y$ can be any solutions, let $x = y$ we have $2x = -b/a$ or $x=-b/2a$

My attempt is plugging $x = -b/2a$ to verify that $xy = c/a$. If so then $b^2/4a^2 = c/a$, which shows that $ b^2 - 4ac$ must always equals to $0$, which is not true.

I would like a verification for my proof.

Thank you.

Comment: The error is where you assume $x=y$.

Comment: I know, but how can l verify it’s an error? Is my above way correct?

Comment: You need to write in LaTex here; it is very hard to read otherwise.
To get you started: surround mathematical clauses with $...$ and the function for a fraction is "\frac{}{}". "\frac{a}{n}" yields $\frac{a}{n}$

Comment: @user545871 it is an error, because you didn't prove $x=y$. You just pulled it out of a hat.

Comment: you proved that when $x=y$ (both roots are the same) then $b^2-4ac=0$ which is true; you did not prove it for any combination of $x$ and $y$

Comment: In Viète's formulas, $x$ and $y$ are not *any* roots, they are *the* roots.

Comment: To expand on egreg's comment: the quadratic has exactly 2 roots. $x$ and $y$ are these two values. whatever they are. What you are told to find is the flaw, which is the assumption that these two roots will be equal. $x$ and $y$ are not just any values that you can make assumptions about. What you have done is not to *find* the flaw, but instead verify that it is indeed a flaw, by showing that it leads to incorrect roots.